flutter, kotlin gradle problem while using location dependencies
enter image description here* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':location:compileDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update /Users/a/Downloads/untitled/android/build.gradle:                                   │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I have solved it only using Android Studio, otherwise I have not been able to solve it and it is by adding the following in the Android/build.gradle file:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

In Android Studio you will see something like "Open for Editing in Android Studio" just open it and it will start downloading and compiling.
I hope it works for you.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22'
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

}
allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
Allready done but not solved
